# If statement in list comprehension with lambda

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda, list-comprehension

I have

```
listName = [[0,1,2,15,16,17,2,3,4,6,8,9]]
```

My line of code

```
[list(g) for k, g in groupby(listName, key=lambda i,j=count(): i-next(j))]
```

is splitting `listName` into `[[0,1,2],[15,16,17],[2,3,4],[6,8,9]]`
I want the split to happen only if the next number is less than the preceding number. i.e
I want my `listName` to split into

```
[[0,1,2,15,16,17],[2,3,4,6,8,9]]
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.  (Once as an addendum to your original question; then again yesterday; and now here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to use a generator function, using `itertools.chain` to create an iterator and flatten your list:

```
listName = [[0, 1, 2, 15, 16, 17, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]]

from itertools import chain
def split(l):
    it = chain(*l)
    prev = next(it)
    tmp = [prev]
    for ele in it:
        if ele < prev:
            yield tmp
            tmp = [ele]
        else:
            tmp.append(ele)
        prev = ele
    yield tmp


print(list(split(listName)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  This worked wonderfully.  Very happy now! :)

Comment: @MikeIssa, no worries, you could hack something with itertools but it would most likely be unreadable